# overrides gets error: "is not a valid parameter"

Tags: python, overriding

I am using `@overrides` from [here](https://pypi.org/project/overrides/) in my project like this:

```
class Parent(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def fetch_events(self):
        pass


class Child_1(Parent, ABC):
    @overrides
    def fetch_events(self, reties=3):
        ...

class Child_2(Parent, ABC):
    @overrides
    def fetch_events(self, transmission_type, reties=3):
        ...
```

Child_1 - everything works nicely
Child_2 - I've got an error like:

```
    : in ExamplePackage
        def fetch_events(self, transmission_type, retries=3):
    /python3.8/site-packages/overrides/overrides.py:88: in overrides
        return _overrides(method, check_signature, check_at_runtime)
    /python3.8/site-packages/overrides/overrides.py:114: in _overrides
        _validate_method(method, super_class, check_signature)
    /python3.8/site-packages/overrides/overrides.py:135: in _validate_method
        ensure_signature_is_compatible(super_method, method, is_static)
    /python3.8/site-packages/overrides/signature.py:106: in ensure_signature_is_compatible
        ensure_no_extra_args_in_sub(super_sig, sub_sig, is_static, method_name)
    python3.8/site-packages/overrides/signature.py:278: in ensure_no_extra_args_in_sub
        raise TypeError(f"{method_name}: `{name}` is not a valid parameter.")
    E   TypeError: Child_2.fetch_events: `transmission_type` is not a valid parameter. got an error:
```

So, basically "overrides" is telling me that I do wrong, by adding a parameter to the method I overwrite? I need in this case, and I thought it is okay. How should I write that correctly, if I need an extra param here?

Comment: You should not change the signature of an abstract method. Take a hypothetical function `def f(b: Parent): b.fetch_events()`. This is supposed to work according to the type definitions, but will fail when it's being passed a `Child_2` instance.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi sorry, my mistake in post - fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This override violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). It should always be possible to use a subclass in the place of a parent class, but the extra required argument makes that impossible.

Either make `transmission_type` optional by providing a default value, or rename the method.